# SSRS 2008 Collapse report section

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Say I have a SSRS 2008 report whose layout is something like the image below.

*Proposed layout*

[image]

Would it be possible to implement a solution that would allow the users to expand \ collapse sections of the report (Report 1, Report 2 etc) when clicking +/- as you can when using a grouped tablix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK figured out how to do it.

I placed both the title and the report into a rectangle, but thats not really required, and set the [ToggleItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220405.aspx) property of the chart to the title text box.

This then gave me the expand / collapse functionality I required. The +/- does seem backwards from what I expected.

*Visible*
[image]

*Hidden*
[image]

**Edit:**

To control the toggle state look at the [InitialToggleState](http://popbi.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/ssrs-toggle-visibility-show-initially-as-expanded/) on the title textbox